# If $\phi:G\rightarrow H$ is an isomorphism, prove that $\vert \phi(x)\vert= \vert x\vert$ for all $x \in G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

I am a bit uncomfortable proving statements in abstract algebra. Can you give me some feed back?

If $\phi:G\rightarrow H$ is an isomorphism, prove that $\vert \phi(x)\vert=
  \vert x\vert$ for all $x \in G$. Deduce that any two isomorphic groups have
        the same number of elements of order $n$ for each $n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Is 
        the result true if $\phi$ is only assumed to be a homomorphism?

Let $|\phi(x)|=n$ and $|x|=m$. Then, $\phi(x)^n=\phi(x^n)=1$ where the second equality holds because $\phi$ is
        homomorphism and the third equality hold by the definition of order.
        Then, $x^n=1$ since $\phi$ being isomorphism $ker\phi = \{1\}$. Hence, $m \leq n$ since $m$ is the order of $x$.
        On the other had, 
        \begin{align}
  \phi(1)&=\phi(x^m) \\
   &=\phi(x)^m \\
   &=1 
  \end{align}
        $(1)$ by the definition of order. $(2)$ holds since $\phi$ is homomorphism. $(3)$ holds since $\phi$ is homomorphism
        and homomorphisms map identity to identity.
        Hence we have $n \leq m$ by the definition of the order of an element.
        Therefore, $n=m$.

Consider $A = \{g \in G | |g|=n\}$, $B=\{h \in H | |h| = n\}$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$. We want to show that 
        $|A|=|B|$. Note, since $\phi$ is bijective, there exists the unique $x \in G$ such that $h=\phi(x)$ for every $h \in H$.
         Then, for each $g \in A$, $|\phi(g)|=n$ by the previous result. Hence, $|A| \leq |B|$.
         On the other hand, for every $h \in B$, $h=\phi(x)$ for some unique $x \in G$. Then, by the previous result,
         $|\phi(x)|=|x|$. Therefore, $|B| \leq |A|$. Hence $|A| = |B|$.

Consider the trivial homomorphism, $\phi : \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times 
   \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Then, $|1|=4$ but $|\phi(1)| = |(0,0)|=1$. Hence, the claim does not hold.

Comment: Everything looks excellent to me. Very nice job!